# How to get the list of applied filters using getActiveFilters?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I am working on the layered navigation. i am trying to get the list of applied filters using `getActiveFilters` of the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State`.

I am trying to understand how `getActiveFilters` function works but not getting.

Please Help me how can i get `getActiveFilters` in magento.

I am trying this on the custom cms page.which is not working.

This code is working on the category page.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862967/magento-get-selected-filter-in-layered-navigation

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
```

Also check this: [How do i get active filters in observer method?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52992/how-do-i-get-active-filters-in-observer-method) is it useful in your case?

Comment: i had tried this but am not able to get the active filters

Comment: What is returned?, nothing at all or empty array? Im not sure but I'm thinking maybe you need to initialize "catalog/layer" when in cms page handle. Add the layer block in layout for example.

Comment: it is returning empty array and i had reffered answer of marius  from http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56340/layered-navigation-isnt-populated-by-collection-attributes-cms-page

Comment: Sorry I can not be of more help. But seems like in your referred thread they came up to a solution. You will need to work it out in your particular case I think.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me,

```
   <?php $mcbls = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State(); ?>
   <?php $asbclv = new Amasty_Shopby_Block_Catalog_Layer_View(); ?>
   <?php $_filters = $mcbls->getActiveFilters(); ?>
   <div class="tool-shop-by" id="tool-shop-by-containor">
        <ul class="tool-result">
          <li>
              <?php 
              foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                  <?php if ($_filter->hasData('children')): 
                    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_filter->getData('children')); exit;?>
                      <?php foreach ($_filter->getData('children') as $child): 
                        ?>
                          <a label="<?php echo $child['label'] ?>" href="<?php echo $child['url'] ?>"><?php echo $child['label'] ?>&nbsp;<span><i class="meigeeadditional-close"></i></span></a>
                      <?php endforeach ?>
                  <?php else: 
                    //echo "<pre>123"; print_r($_filter->getData('children')); exit;?>
                      <a href="<?php echo $_filter->getRemoveUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_filter->getLabel(); ?><span><i class="meigeeadditional-close"></i></span></a>
                  <?php endif ?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <?php if (count($_filters)): ?>
        <div class="actions"> <a href="<?php echo $asbclv->getClearUrl() ?>" class="clear_all">Clear all</a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
```